# Do not allow decimal numbers in UserForm TextBox - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

How to check for only Whole numbers ? no decimals allowed.

```vb
'Below is the code to check for numbers
For j = 1 To 59
    If Me.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value = "" Then
    Else
        If Not IsNumeric(Me.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value) Then
        MsgBox "only numbers are allowed"
        Cancel = False
        Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
Next j
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Is String Digits?

**A Quick Fix**

```vb
' Below is the code to check for numbers
Dim j As Long
Dim cString As String

For j = 1 To 59
    cString = Me.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value
    If Len(cString) = 0 Then
        'MsgBox "At least one digit is necessary!", vbExclamation
    ElseIf Not (cString Like String(Len(cString), "#")) Then
        MsgBox "Only digits are allowed!", vbCritical
        Cancel = False ' ?
        Exit Sub
    Else ' valid input
    End If
Next j
```

**A Function**

- The `If` statement in the previous code is 'splitting' the following function's two operations.

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns a boolean indicating whether all characters of a string
'               are digits.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function IsDigits(ByVal S As String) As Boolean
    If Len(S) > 0 Then IsDigits = S Like String(Len(S), "#")
End Function
```

Comment: Hello Vbasic2008, thank you once again for the quick fix. The solution earlier worked fine for whole number. What if I need to allow -ve numbers as well but no decimals ?

Comment: Try: `cString = Replace(Me.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value, "-", "", 1, 1)`.

Comment: Again, it worked to the point. Thanks. Before coming here, even I tried replace() but with Like and string functions. Did not work though. Thanks for the quick professional fix.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is a better user experience to check as the user types not after the fact.  Try something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
   If Not GoodKeyPress(KeyAscii) Then KeyAscii = 0
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
   If Not GoodKeyPress(KeyAscii) Then KeyAscii = 0
End Sub

Private Function GoodKeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger) As Boolean
   If KeyAscii = 46 Then MsgBox "No decimal allowed"

   'allow only numbers, negative sign and backspace
   If (KeyAscii >= 48 And KeyAscii <= 57) Or KeyAscii = 45 Or KeyAscii = 8 Then GoodKeyPress = True
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Brian, Thank you for the response. I agree with your "user experience" suggestion. What about restricting user to only whole numbers ? with a Msg box: "No decimal allowed" if entered.

Comment: You could add an If statement to the above.  I modified the code accordingly.

Comment: Dear Brain, thanks again for the response. I am a beginner in VBA. That said, I partly understand your solution but not sure how (or) where to use optionexplicit within the loop of 1-59 textboxes in a Userform. Secondly, in addition to above, I need to allow negative numbers as well. I genuinely appreciate your response.

Comment: Option Explicit is typically the first line of code in the file, before any variables, functions, or subs.  Also, I updated the code to allow entry of a negative sign.

Comment: I understand, how to apply this to a textbox range of 1-59, in a userform?

Comment: You will notice that the above code is for TextBox1.  You would have the same code for any other TextBox.  This being the case, I would move the above code into a Function called from all the KeyPress events.  A little tedious but doable.  An advanced technique would be to use a class to help cut down on code but since you are a beginner this approach may not be the best way to go.